# How to get byte length of a base64 string in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'd like to calculate the size of an image file received as base64 encoded string like:

```
'data:image/png;base64,aBdiVBORw0fKGgoAAA...'
```

in order to  make sure that the file is not larger than certain size, say 5MB.

How can I acheive this in node.js?

I've seen similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3644167/7937129) but could not apply the answer in my node app as I get:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to remove the data... part

```
const img = 'data:image/png;base64,aBdiVBORw0fKGgoAAA';
const buffer = Buffer.from(img.substring(img.indexOf(',') + 1));
console.log("Byte length: " + buffer.length);
console.log("MB: " + buffer.length / 1e+6);
```

Comment: Great. How can I convert it to MB?

Comment: Added it to the answer @Babr

Comment: I think this was not parsing the string as base64.

Comment: You need to add `'base64'` as second argument of `Buffer.from()` @bambam

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there is not much to it.
If you know the size of the Base64 image all you have to do is divide by 1.37.
As Base64 algorithm is linear the result is also.
For more info see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#MIME).

To calculate the string size that you already have you can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3644167/1571605):

```
function byteCount(s) {
    return encodeURI(s).split(/%..|./).length - 1;
}
```

and divide the result by 1.37.

Comment: As I said, I receive the image as a string inside json object, so I don't know the size of the image file, hence the question.

Comment: yeah - caught that a little late. See my edited answer

Comment: as a note: 1.37 is not an exact number but should be close, the source you linked says we should also be adding size of headers

Answer (score 1):

```
var src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7";

var base64str = src.substring(src.indexOf(',') + 1)
var decoded = atob(base64str);

console.log("FileSize: " + decoded.length);
```

Comment: This answer is more accurate. Thank you.